# updating a mysql database from a pandas dataframe wiht executemany

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am using `mysqldb` to try to update a lot of records in a database.

```
cur.executemany("""UPDATE {} set {} =%s Where id = %s """.format(table, ' = %s, '.join(col)),updates.values.tolist())
```

I get the error message...

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...
```

So I tried outputting the actual sql update statement as that error message wasn't helpful using the following code:

```
cur.execute('set profiling = 1')
    try:

        cur.executemany("""UPDATE {} set {} =%s Where id = %s """.format(table, ' = %s, '.join(col)),updates.values.tolist())
    except Exception:
        cur.execute('show profiles')
        for row in cur:
            print(row)
```

That print statement seems to cut off the update statement at 300 characters. I can't find anything in the documentation about limits so I am wondering is this the print statement limiting or is it mysqldb?

Is there a way I can generate the update statement with just `python` rather than `mysqldb` to see the full statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see exactly what the cursor was executing, you can use the `cursor.statement` command as shown [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-statement.html) in the API. That may help with the debugging.

I don't have experience with the mySQL adapter, but I work with the PostgreSQL adapter on a daily basis. At least in that context, it is recommended not to format your query string directly, but let the second argument in the `cursor.execute` statement do the substitution. This avoids problems with quoted strings and such. Here is an example, the second one is correct (at least for Postgres):

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE mytbl SET mycol = %s WHERE mycol2 = %s""".format(val, cond))

cur.execute("""UPDATE mytbl SET mycol = %(myval)s WHERE mycol2 = %(mycond)s""", {'myval': val, 'mycond': cond})
```

This can result in the query

> UPDATE mytbl SET mycol = abc WHERE mycol2 = xyz

instead of

> UPDATE mytbl SET mycol = 'abc' WHERE mycol2 = 'xyz'.

You would have needed to explicitly add those quotes if you do the value substitution in the query yourself, which becomes annoying and circumvents the type handling of the database adapter (keep in mind this was only a text example). [See the API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) for a bit more information on this notation and the `cursor.executemany` command.